# Extrema of functions which involve product with exponential function

Tags: calculus

How to find extrema of product function $y(t)=e^{-t}\,\sin t$? I applied the usual approach by finding critical points. It gave max at $t= \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{9\pi}{4}, \frac{17\pi}{4}, \dots $ and min at $t=\frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{13\pi}{4}, \frac{13\pi}{4}, \dots $ However, when I plot graph of this function, it turns out that max and min are not at these points (which should not be the case). How to explain two different outcomes from two approaches? Where is the mistake? I appreciate any help on this issue. Thank you.

Here is how I found extrema using calculus: $\dot{y}(t)=e^{-t} \left(\cos t -\sin t \right)=0$ implies $\cos t -\sin t =0$. This gives critical points $t= \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{9\pi}{4}, \frac{17\pi}{4}, \dots $. Using second derivative test, it is easy to find the max and min given above in the statement.

Shah

Comment: Can you show your usual approach's calculations?

Comment: Where did the plot (can you perhaps show us that) make you think the max and min where?

Comment: I don't find any any way to upload files in comments but it is a straightforard plot. You can plot it by MATLAB or any other poltting utility.

Comment: You can't put files in comments, but you should be able to edit in into the question. And the question wasn't what I can see from the graph, but what it made you think.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are right : maxima are at $\frac{\pi}{4} + 2 k \pi$ and minima at $\frac{5 \pi}{4} + 2 k \pi$ for any integer $k$. I have tried plotting your function and these min and max match. Just be careful that you have to zoom in order to see the extrema far from $0$ since the $e^{-t}$ factor becomes very small.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hugo! I checked graph carefully. The max occurs at $t=1.1$ which is not equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}=0.79$. Similarly, there is difference between the min in the graph $t=4.28$ and the min obtained using Calculus $t=5\frac{\pi}{4}=3.92$.

Comment: Could you share how you get your graph?

Comment: Using plot command of MATLAB.

Comment: I don't have MATLAB, and I'm not going to install (it's also proprietary crap) it just to help you. But the exponential function is not special, local extrema still corresponds to the derivative being zero, so if you see an extremum that doesn't  corespond to one of those points you've made an error, either in producing the graph or in reading it. Without seeing *your* graph, we can't say which .